# @SerialInfo - How to manage user-defined serial annotations with Kotlinx serialization?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, annotations, kotlinx.serialization

### Kotlinx serialization documentation

According to `Kotlinx.serialization` user-defined annotations [doc](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/examples.md#user-defined-serial-annotations):

> *"Inside a process of serialization/deserialization,* your own annotation class *are available in `SerialDescriptor` object"* :

```
override fun encodeElement(desc: SerialDescriptor, index: Int): Boolean {
    val annotations = desc.getElementAnnotations(index)
    ...
}
```

### What I want to do

I need a `@Transient` equivalent, but conditional:

- classic way where : `Json.stringify(serializer, myClass)` works as usual.
- custom way where : `Json.stringify(customSerializer, myClass)` would return usual json but exculding all `@MyAnnotation`-tagged values.

Here is my code

```
@SerialInfo
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class CustomAnnotation

@Serializable
data class MyClass(val a: String, @CustomAnnotation val b: Int = -1)
```

And I would like to build a custom Serializer and achieve something like

```
override fun encodeElement(desc: SerialDescriptor, index: Int): Boolean {
    val isTaggedAsCustomAnnotation = desc.getElementAnnotations(index).any{ it is CustomAnnotation }
    val myCondition = mySerializer.getMyConditionBlablabla

    if(myCondition && isTaggedAsCustomAnnotation) {
        encode()    
    }
    ...
}
```

### What I found

```
abstract class ElementValueEncoder : Encoder, CompositeEncoder {
    ...
    open fun encodeElement(desc: SerialDescriptor, index: Int): Boolean = true
}
```

But I don't know how I can build a custom Serializer so that I can override that function `Encoder.encodeElement`. Where can I access to ElementValueEncoder in a custom Serializer ?

I also found this [sample demo](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/examples/example-jvm/src/TaggedDemo.kt) in kotlinx.serialization github repo. It's using `TaggedEncoder` & `TaggedDecoder` where I'm able to override `encodeTaggedValue`. But here again I don't know how I can use those encoder/decoder in a process of serialization/deserialization.

### Finally

Where can I override `fun encodeElement(desc: SerialDescriptor, index: Int): Boolean`, and how I can handle my own-defined serialization annotation ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to grasp the difference between Serializer and Encoder. Serializer (represented by `KSerializer`) defines how your class looks like, and Encoder (represented by e.g. `JsonOutput`) defines how data will be recorded. You can find more info on that topic here: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/serialization.md#core-api-overview-and-mental-model .

So, custom annotations feature is mainly used for providing *format-specific* information to Encoder. Typical usage of such an annotation is `ProtoId` – property id, specific to protobuf format, that should be recognized by `ProtobufEncoder`. Such annotations are usually defined by format authors alongside their encoders.

What you want to do here, as I can see, is to use already existing encoder (JSON format), so overriding `encodeElement` is impossible since Json encoders can not be subclassed. I'd advise you to use [custom json transofrming serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json_transformations.md#transformation-examples-default-values-mainupulation) to achieve your goal. Unfortunately, currently kotlinx.serialization does not have mechanism to generalize such a transformation, so you need to write such serializer for each class.